# Can't instantiate simple class

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

could somebody tell me what's wrong with my code please? I don't understand the compiler error messages. :(

ItemContainer.h:

```
class ItemContainer
{
    class MyBase
    { // <- Line 14
    public:
        bool bIsPointer;
        class MyDerived* instancePtr;

        MyBase(class MyDerived* ptr)
        {
            bIsPointer = true;
            instancePtr = ptr;
        }
    };

    class MyDerived : public MyBase
    {
    public:
        MyDerived() : MyBase(nullptr)
        {
            bIsPointer = false;
        }
    };

    /* ... */
};
```

ItemContainer.cpp:

```
void ItemContainer::Test()
{
    MyDerived * myDerivedPtr;
    MyBase myBase = MyBase(myDerivedPtr); // <- Line 175
}
```

The compiler throws the following error at me:

- ItemContainer.cpp(175): error C2440: '': cannot convert from 'ItemContainer::MyDerived *' to 'ItemContainer::MyBase'
- ItemContainer.cpp(175): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
- ItemContainer.cpp(175): error C2512: 'ItemContainer::MyBase': no appropriate default constructor available
- ItemContainer.h(14): note: see declaration of 'ItemContainer::MyBase'

Comment: Just like `Mybase` is declared as an inner class of `ItemContainer`, `class myDerived *` declares an inner class of `MyBase`, which has nothing to do with `myDerived` inner class of `ItemContainer`. You need to move the forward declaration up one level. You have two different `MyDerived`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two classes called `MyDerived`, `ItemContainer::MyBase::MyDerived` and `ItemContainer::MyDerived`.

To fix this, add `class MyDerived;` before the definition of `class MyBase`.

Compiling with a high warning level (`/W4`) may get a warning, and omitting the `class` keywords within `MyBase` would have resulted in a different compiler error that would have made the problem easier to see.

Comment: "add class `MyDerived` before the definition of class `MyBase`." No can do. `MyDerived` inherits `MyBase`.

Comment: @user4581301 Just declare `class MyDerived;`, followed by the definition of `class MyBase`, then the definition of `class MyDerived`.

Comment: Get you now. Recommend a reword. "To fix this, add `class MyDerived` before the definition of `class MyBase`." reads like "Define `MyDerived` ahead of `MyBase`" Suggest "To fix this, forward declare `class MyDerived` before the definition of `class MyBase`." to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score -1):

The error description is ambiguous ( many thank to Visual Studio ).
I think you want to instanciate new `MyBase` object.

`MyBase* myBase = new MyBase(myDerivedPtr);`

Or simply,a stack-constructed object

`MyBase myBase(myDerivedPtr);`

Comment: I don't really see how this solves anything, stuff like `MyBase* myBase = new MyBase(myDerivedPtr);` is generally not to be encouraged. Also what do you mean by "a stack-constructed object" , the C++ standard does not mandate a "stack".

Comment: When you instantiate an Object, this object is created in the Stack. Object created using new are a heap constructed object. @George

Comment: It's implementation-defined whether or not your statement is true. The only thing you can really say is that objects created using the `new` keyword are dynamically allocated and non-dynamically allocated objects are automatically allocated.